# remove item from list if it does not match substring, regardless of the formatting

Tags: python, string, substring, matching

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['full_string'] = [['apples and bananas', 'applesandbananasamongstothers', 'something else'], 
          ['ApplesandBananas', 'apples and Bananas', 'bananas']]
df['substring'] = ['apples and bananas', 'apples and bananas']
```

The desired outcome is to keep the items in df['full_string'] which contain text that is found in df['substring'], while taking into account that:

- casing, higher case or lowercase should not matter
- the spacing between the words
- the words may contain other text that is not related to the text in df['substring']

Desired outcome:

```
df['outcome'] = [['apples and bananas', 'applesandbananasamongstothers'], 
      ['ApplesandBananas', 'apples and Bananas', 'bananas']]
```

What I have tried is to get the first keyword of df['substring'] to use that as a matcher with df['full_string'], however, this did not allow me to retain the 'bananas' element in the second row of the dataframe.

(**This is not working well on the dummy data**):

```
first_keyword = []
for i in df['substring']:
    first_keyword.append(i.split(' ', 1)[0])

df['first_keyword'] = first_keyword

df['C'] = [x[0].lower() in (x[1].lower()) for x in zip(df['first_keyword'], df['full_string'])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the example, I chose to work with list containing your dummy data. You'll need to adapt it to your problem.
Moreover, I interpret your sentence "The desired outcome is to keep the items in df['full_string'] which contain text that is found in df['substring']" as text = word.

```
full_str = ['apples and bananas', 'applesandbananasamongstothers', 'something else', 
           'ApplesandBananas', 'apples and Bananas', 'bananas']
sub_str = ['apples and bananas', 'red and blue']

# Extract words from sub strings
words_in_sub = [elt.split() for elt in sub_str]
# Flatten and remove duplicates
words_in_sub = list(set([item for sublist in words_in_sub for item in sublist]))

# Init output
output = list()
# Loop on the strings in full string
for full_s in full_str:
    # Loop on the words to look for
    for word in words_in_sub:
        if word.lower() in full_s.lower():
            output.append(full_s)
            break
```

Output:

```
In: output
Out: 
['apples and bananas',
 'applesandbananasamongstothers',
 'ApplesandBananas',
 'apples and Bananas',
 'bananas']
```

The lower/upper case is taken care of in the if condition. The spacing is taken care of by the `in` statement. The presence of other text in `full_s` is taken care of by the `in` statement. The `in` statement return True if the word is present somewhere in the string. The only case where it will return False while the word might be considered as present in the string is if the word is cut in to two by a space, for instance `'bana naan dapp les'`. This example would not be kept in the output list.

**EDIT:** With multiple rows. You could also just flatten the list and use the first code.

```
full_str = [['apples and bananas', 'applesandbananasamongstothers', 'something else'], 
            ['ApplesandBananas', 'apples and Bananas', 'bananas']]
sub_str = [['apples and bananas'], ['apples and bananas']]

# Assuming same number of rows between full_str and sub_str
# And you want to keep element of full_str[k] according to sub strings in sub_str[k]
number_of_rows = len(full_str)
for k in range(number_of_rows):
    # Extract words from sub strings
    words_in_sub = [elt.split() for elt in sub_str[k]]
    # Flatten and remove duplicates
    words_in_sub = list(set([item for sublist in words_in_sub for item in sublist]))

    # Init output
    output = list()
    # Loop on the strings in full string
    for full_s in full_str[k]:
        # Loop on the words to look for
        for word in words_in_sub:
            if word.lower() in full_s.lower():
                output.append(full_s)
                break
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and elaborate response. This is definitely helping out and I could adapt it to my problem. The only modification that I am struggling with that instead of returning a list of output, I want to filter the rows that contain a 'match'. When taking your dummy data as an example, the lists of full_str and sub_str would be of equal length before and after the string matching.

Comment: @bjornvandijkman I don't understand what you mean by "the list of full_str and sub_str would be of equal length before and after the string matching". `full_str` has 6 elements, while the list `sub_str` has only 2.

Comment: In my dummy data both columns full string and substring have 2 rows. From the first row I want to remove ''something else' from 'full string' while keeping the others. In the second row I want to keep all elements in 'full row'. Both the input and the output dataframe would therefore contain 2 rows (with 1 less element).

Comment: @bjornvandijkman Then simply add one more for loops on the rows and treat them one by one. The structure would be `for r in rows: for full_s in full_str: for words in words_in_sub:`. I think there must be a more straightforward and vectorized way to do what you want directly in pandas, but if your dataframe isn't too big, then a simple for loop implementation is good enough. I'll edit my example to add this + the loop on the substring.

Comment: @bjornvandijkman I chose to modify a bit the `sub_str` as I do not understand in your example why you define it as`df['substring'] = ['apples and bananas', 'apples and bananas']`. You define it as a list with twice the same element. Instead, I decided to defined it as a list of list, containing 2 rows, each with the same element.

Comment: Thanks :) will check it out later today and will let you know if it worked out!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this did the trick! The only thing that I changed was to move `output = list()` above the for loop.